# CORS policy error when trying to render image from pinata ipfs

Tags: web3js, ipfs, alchemy, pinata

[image]    pinata.js file

```
const FormData = require("form-data");

export const uploadJSONToIPFS = async (JSONBody) => {

  const url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinJSONToIPFS`;

  //making axios POST request to Pinata ⬇️

  return axios

    .post(url, JSONBody, {

      headers: {

        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",

        pinata_api_key: key,

        pinata_secret_api_key: secret,

      },

    })

    .then(function (response) {

      return {

        success: true,

        pinataURL:

          "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/" + response.data.IpfsHash,

      };

    })

    .catch(function (error) {

      console.log(error);

      return {

        success: false,

        message: error.message,

      };
    });
};

export const uploadFileToIPFS = async (file) => {

  const url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS`;

  //making axios POST request to Pinata ⬇️


  let data = new FormData();

  data.append("file", file);

  const metadata = JSON.stringify({

    name: "testname",
    keyvalues: {
      exampleKey: "exampleValue",
    },
  });
  data.append("pinataMetadata", metadata);

  //pinataOptions are optional

  const pinataOptions = JSON.stringify({

    cidVersion: 0,

    customPinPolicy: {

      regions: [

        {
          id: "FRA1",
          desiredReplicationCount: 1,
        },
        {
          id: "NYC1",
          desiredReplicationCount: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
  });
  data.append("pinataOptions", pinataOptions);


  return axios

    .post(url, data, {

      maxBodyLength: "Infinity",

      headers: {

        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",

        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
    enter code here
        pinata_api_key: key,
        pinata_secret_api_key: secret,
        Accept: "text/plain",
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("image uploaded", response.data.IpfsHash);
      return {
        success: true,
        pinataURL:
          "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/" + response.data.IpfsHash,
      };
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return {
        success: false,
        message: error.message,
      };
    });
};
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkDqe.jpg
```

tried all the solutions available on internet not able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding this extension to chrome
CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
"https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en"